Modify Emacs built-in .el files, but no effect after restarting Emacs
I'd like to debug some Emacs build-in .el source code. For example, start-process in subr.el.
I added a log to this function, i.e. (message "Hello")
(defun start-process (name buffer program &rest program-args)
  "Start a program ..."
  (unless (fboundp 'make-process)
    (error "Emacs was compiled without subprocess support"))
  (message "Hello") ;; <---- MY LOG!
  (apply #'make-process
     (append (list :name name :buffer buffer)
         (if program
             (list :command (cons program program-args))))))

then evaluated this function, called (start-process "test" "testbuffer" "cmd.exe") and the *Message* buffer displayed the log "Hello" as expected.
Now I go to the location of subr.el: C:/emacs-28.2/share/emacs/28.2/lisp, remove subr.elc, restart Emacs and call (start-process "test" "testbuffer" "cmd.exe") agian, but this time Hello is not shown.
I don't know what happens here. Even after removing both subr.el and subr.elc, the start-process can still be invoked normally.
The question:
Is there way to modify Emacs built-in .el files without evaluate it manually?
P.s. I found that there is a subr-13adf6a6-52874174.eln in C:/emacs-28.2/lib/emacs/28.2/native-lisp/28.2-5a1d5235/preloaded. I've tried deleting this file, but Emacs won't start anymore.
Anyone can give me some information? Thanks.

You're running into How does Emacs manage to start instantaneously with many el-files?
start-process is defined in the subr library, which is one of the libraries loaded by loadup.el at build time, and consequently pre-loaded in the Emacs you run.  Modifying those source files after building Emacs has no effect.
That doesn't mean you can't redefine that function; you just can't do it by editing the subr.el source.  (Or not unless you explicitly load the modified library after start-up.)

Put one of subr.el, subr.elc, or sub.eln back and Emacs will be able to start. Hopefully you kept backups.
You should not bother to modify the source files that come with Emacs. Either the modifications will be ignored, because there is a compiled version that gets read instead or because the file is actually built–in to the memory image, or a future version of Emacs will overwrite the file anyway.
Instead, if you want to redefine something just redefine it in your init file. Your init file is pretty much the last thing that gets loaded, so anything you define there will supersede any previous definitions.

When did this start? I seem to remember that Emacs once supported direct modification of build-in .el files (or my memorization is wrong?) So currently there is no way to modify Emacs build-in .el directly? (I know we can put functions into init file to override behavior.)
